# Schedule task to run everyday at specific time with Quartz.NET

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.NET for doing a task everyday at specific hour and this is my code:

```
public class TestSchedule : ISchedule
    {
        public void Run()
        {

            DateTimeOffset startTime = DateBuilder.FutureDate(2, IntervalUnit.Second);

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
                                       .WithIdentity("job1")
                                       .Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                             .WithIdentity("trigger1")
                                             .StartAt(startTime)
                                             .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x.OnEveryDay().StartingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(7, 0)).WithRepeatCount(0))
                                             .Build();

            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler sc = sf.GetScheduler();
            sc.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

            sc.Start();
        }
    }
```

my code is working, but problem is that works only once(it seems that , it's because `WithRepeatCount(0)` ) 
now, how can say that run everyday at 7 o'clock?
**PS : I don't want use `CronTrigger` to do that.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/topic2206.html) only support **repeatCount**.

> This trigger also supports "repeatCount" feature to end the trigger
>   fire time after a certain number of count is reached. Just as the
>   SimpleTrigger, setting repeatCount=0 means trigger will fire once
>   only! Setting any positive count then the trigger will repeat count +
>   1 times. Unlike SimpleTrigger, the default value of repeatCount of
>   this trigger is set to REPEAT_INDEFINITELY instead of 0 though.

Cron expressions are beautiful and there's loads of [tools](http://www.cronmaker.com/) which can help you to achieve what you're looking for.

Another alternative would be to use a [SimpleTriggerImpl](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/topic2247.html) and set the interval every 24 hours:

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("trigger1")
        .StartAt(startTime)
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.RepeatForever().WithIntervalInHours(24))
        .Build();
```

Comment: Another solution would be `.EndingDailyAfterCount(1)` instead of `.WithIntervalInHours(24)`. So you won't get into troubles with DST (daylight saving time) related issues.

Comment: HOw to mention the time say every morning 2:00 am? startTime is of type DateTime  and we need to mention the date as well correct?

Comment: @Sebastian: It depends which version of Quartz.net you are using. Loads of things have changed since I posted this answer. The version I was using in this sample would have accepted a `DateTimeOffset` for the method `StartAt`. DateTime field would be fine too, as long as you add the time. Running every 24h would respect your schedule.